# DateTimePicker Deletes first character double characters are used on 'Day' C# WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

When I input a DOB into the `DateTimePicker`, on my `winforms` project the first character gets removed if I input a day with 2 characters .
E.g it turns 25/08/2017 to 05/08/2017. However It's fine the second time!

**Constructors:**

```
dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Today; // Ensures no future dates are set.
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
```

**Events handlers**

*ValueChanged*

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";             
if (dateTimePicker1.Checked == false)
{
dateTimePicker1.Enabled = false;
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
}
```

*PreviewKeyDown*

```
if (dateTimePicker1.Checked == true)
{
   dateTimePicker1.Enabled = true;
   dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short 
}
```

The issue is that to activate the date time picker the first character is missed and the default date is used, which is 01/01/1998 so once the first Char is pressed this date gets brought into the datetimepicker, until the second letter is pressed, hence the 25 turning to 5 as it only receives 5.
Any ideas would be well reicvied as this is really bugging me I know its it inside the value changed event handler as it only happens when You tab into it and Type

Comment: Changing the Format property has nasty side-effects.  It is a "difficult" property, it can only be specified when the underlying native control is created.  So Winforms has to do something special, it destroys the native control and recreates it again.  That has side-effects, the control no longer remembers that you were busy entering the day.  It is not obvious why PreviewKeyDown is useful here, you'll probably have to live without it.

Comment: I have just realised there is really not an essentiall need for the PreviewKeyDown, Have you any ideas on how toto get round this side-effect? Because I need to be able to have the user to tab and activate the box by this I have a default date which if left on it will change the field to 0

Comment: Because The reason I have used it is to allow the user to tab intot the control and start typing rather than click on the calender

Comment: I can't guess why this is necessary.  As long as you keep the format set to Custom, tabbing into DTP sets the focus on the day part and typing numbers is immediately effective.  When you switch it to Long then you have the additional hazard of the month being first, depends on where you live.

Comment: The reason For this is because I need the date time picker to be blank on construction and as sson as the begin typing change the focus to the DTP. Th  reason for this was that I neeed to Eradicate null values using the default date, so if it was left null it.